# Video Call Using WebRtc

Tags: android, sockets, video-streaming, webrtc

I want to develop video calling app using webrtc without any third party SDK. I integrated this demo
https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC
But I don't find any demo that gives me Peer To Peer Connection between two mobile.

Comment: Generally, a peer-to-peer connection is not possible, particularly with mobile devices. There is some intermediary server (e.g., STUN) that bridges the two networks.

Comment: @CommonsWare STUN is not an intermediary server,  TURN is. Mobile devices are not a problem. Mobile *networks* often are, because they often use symmetrical NATs or block UDP. But with wifi there's rarely a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this: [Android RTC Github](https://github.com/GleasonK/AndroidRTC) I have build my app using this sample, which is working pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout is my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47117314/2437655) on `QuickBlox` integration.

> I want to develop video calling app using webrtc without any third
>   party SDK. I integrated this demo https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC

I hope AndroidRTC is a webrtc-client module which is a third party sdk.

---

> I don't find any demo that gives me Peer To Peer Connection between
>   two mobile.

WebRTC ("Web Real-Time Communication") is a collection of communications protocols and application programming interfaces that enable ***real-time communication over peer-to-peer connections.*** 
[source: wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC)

---

Update: 8 May

My answer is deleted due to close vote on the question (Not my answer)

[image]

Here was my answer:

I hope this will give you a head start.

[QuickBlox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47117314/2437655) provides a backend infrastructure for chat, API, and dashboard at free of cost.

`QuickBlox` also provides an open-source, cross-platform, 
video calling and instant messaging app solution called [Q-municate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC)

You can find ready-made apps with a wide range of communication features included (such as messaging, file transfer, push notifications, audio/video calls)

[Qmunicate Android chat application source code](https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-android)

[Qmunicate iOS chat application source code](https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-ios)

[Qmunicate Web chat application source code](https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-web)

---

However, if you are only interested in video calling to try checking the selected SDK only.

For Android SDK : https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk

You can use [sample-videochat-webrtc](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-videochat-webrtc) along with [quickblox-core-module](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-core)

*ps: no need to add other modules for video calling except core module.*

Here is the complete sample [doc](https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android) for the video WebRTC sample.

Comment: your answer link is is dead.

Comment: @RaviVaniya Answer added.